# suspicious, suspectful, or suspected

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, synonyms

I want some example sentences with each of the words (used as adjectives) to better understand how I can use them! The sentence I want to write is:

> The actual culprit is portrayed as a well-educated scientific man, which makes him less _____.

Should I use *suspectful* here? In my understanding is someone suspicious when they suspect something, and a thing or a person can be suspectful when they are suspected. Am I right?

Comment: The [ell.se] Stack Exchange might have been an even better place for this question. (Just letting you know it exists.) P.S. I'd use _suspicious_, because _suspectful_ is a rather uncommon word, and _suspected_, while more common, is mostly used as a verb. [Check out the ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suspicious%2Csuspectful%2Csuspected_VERB%2Csuspected_ADJ&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 1):

Suspicious is the common option. Its meanings can go both ways, used to describe how they think or how other people think of them, depending on the context. I think suspected would be fine too.

EDIT: I am sorry for the lack of examples. I should have read the full question.